# Table not fitting on screen

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm having a problem with my css and cant seem to fix it. the table i have wont fix on the page.

this is seen at : https://shiftscloud.herokuapp.com/newrosters.php

can't seem to find the problem.

my CSS:

```
.manreq  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;background-color:#a0d4a4}
.manreq td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px  5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.manreq th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.manreq .tg-zd20{font-size:22px;text-align:center}
.manreq .tg-wrg0{font-size:22px;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.manreq .tg-wv9z{font-size:22px;text-align:center}
.manreq .tg-qcjy{font-size:22px;vertical-align:top}
.manreq .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top;width:20px}



.roster  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;background-color:#33FF66;padding:5px;}
.roster td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:5px 10px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.roster th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:5px 10px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.roster .tg-baqh{text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.roster .tg-jlrw{font-size:16px;text-align:center}
.roster .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top;width:20px}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {.tg {width: auto !important;}.tg col {width: auto !important;}.tg-wrap {overflow-x: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}}
```

Comment: Your Table contains nested Elements like Input-Fields (which are set to 75%). Now if you want everything to fit inside of the Parent container which is 1140px, you must compromise the size of your input field and i don't think that's what you want. So, better, make the Container Scrollable (horizontally) by adding this style to your css: ***div.tg-wrap {
    overflow: auto;
}***

Comment: @Poiz i dont mind making my input fields smaller if it means they all fit but how do i do it?

Comment: If you want a complete solution with Flexible Widths; you can check out this Tutorial: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/flexible_width.html

Comment: Referring to an off-site page is of no value to future visitors. Show your minimally, relevant HTML here cause, showing only the CSS, is like showing your crayons but not the coloring book. Also, your comments before the doctype on that page will immediately throw IE into quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding this Style to your CSS File:

```
div.tg-wrap {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

At least you can scroll Horizontally afterwards... if you want a robust solution with Flexible Width; you can check out this Tutorial: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/flexible_width.html

Answer (score 0):

Try adding table-layout: fixed to your .roster class:

```
.roster {
    table-layout: fixed; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

This should reduce your table to within the constraints of your window, but your fields might not be 100% readable since your font-size is quite large. You might need to reduce your font size.

Also, you can update your .rosterform class to 100% if you wish to make full use of the empty spaces:

```
.rosterform {
    width: 100%;
}
```